# Having trouble with NSTimer (Swift)

Tags: swift, nstimer

--EDITED WITH UPDATED INFORMATION--

What I wish to do is call a function named `timerFunc` once every five seconds using a `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method, the issue seems is that during runtime, I get the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-      
[Animation.ViewController timerFunc:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe548d66040'
```

In the output log. I've been looking up other people's NSTimers to no avail, I see quite a few have the selector as `selector: Selector("timerFunc:")` instead of `selector: Selector("timerFunc")` both ways, however, give the error. Another thing is that both the timerFunc function and the NSTimer are inside of viewDidLoad, are there any issues with that? Any insight on the problem is greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

timerFunc below

```
func timerFunc(){

    println("Timer")
}
```

NSTimer below

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        5.0,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("timerFunc"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
```

Comment: What is the signature of your timerFunc?

Comment: @vacawama  Signature? Currently I'm trying to get NSTimer to work, so my timerFunc is only a `println("Timer")` I added my timerFunc to the main question. I've figured out my previous question, it was just that I didn't need to call timeInterval:, it messed it up for some reason. The current issue is that it doesn't give me an error in the editor, but when I run it the output log says `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Animation.ViewController timerFunc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc53e67010` among several lines of gibberish.

Comment: I was just making sure your `timerFunc` didn't take a parameter.  Yours doesn't, so that isn't the problem. Is your `timerFunc` a method of the `ViewController`?

Comment: @vacawama My timerFunc is a function inside of viewDidLoad, which is inside of ViewController. I tested to see if it could be called by my NSTimer by writing a `timerFunc()` right next to my NSTimer location, proving it is accessible to where my NSTimer is. Perhaps, however, my NSTimer doesn't have access within my viewDidLoad? Should I create a whole new class with a special subclass for it? If so, what subclass?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: How to target class-level function in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Another thing is that both the timerFunc function and the NSTimer are inside of viewDidLoad, are there any issues with that?**

Yes.  That is your problem.  The `timerFunc` can't be nested inside of `viewDidLoad`, it must be a top level function at the same level as `viewDidLoad`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ....
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func timerFunc() {
        println("Timer")
    }

}
```

When the timer fires, it will call the function specified by the selector on the the object designated by target.  That is, it will call `self.timerFunc()`.  When your `timerFunc()` is nested inside of `ViewDidLoad`, it can't find it.

Comment: As for why: methods invoked dynamically using a selector must be old school objc methods. All methods of a class inheriting from NSObject are by default, but if you're not extending NSObject you can mark them with `@objc`.

Answer (score 11):

Timers will not work with private method callbacks. Also, **make sure your class inherits from NSObject**. Pure Swift classes will not work.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/NxSoftware/NxSwiftTimer

Comment: Yeh, that was my issue, class needs to inherit from `NSObject`!

Comment: +500 for NSObject thing!

Comment: i seem to have the same problem with a public function of a private class, if i set my private class as internal instead, it works all fine, any idea why @Antoine?

Comment: This is not enough information for me to give a good answer. I would suggest to open a new thread with some code examples instead.

Answer (score 3):

My problem with this was the selector was pointing at a private function.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of a Swift method does not include a label. All others generally do. You should expect the syntax to be:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I studied more closely to other people's code and came to that conclusion, however, now whenever I run it the output log gives me the error of `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Animation.ViewController timerFunc]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc53e67010` How will I catch this exception>?

Comment: I just clarified that it is implemented by commenting out my NSTimer and calling the timerFunc with a timerFunc() line. It does seem that it's just not recognizing timerFunc as a selector, although I don't know why.

Comment: I just thought, does it matter where I have my NSTimer? Right now it's in viewDidLoad..

Answer (score 1):

When using a selector in Swift you need to use the **Selector()** pseudo-function around the name of the function:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0,   target: self, 
                                            selector: Selector("timerFunc"), 
                                            userInfo: nil,
                                             repeats: true);
```

The reason for the seemingly confusing errors I suspect is due to the compilers inability to match your argument list to a particular method, due to the selector name being of the wrong type (string rather than selector).

This also explains the fact that when you did manage to get it to compile (as mentioned in the comments to another answer) it failed at runtime.  The type checking at compile time fails to pick up this sort of error (hence the runtime exception reporting the '*unrecognized selector*').

Comment: Generally speaking you don't need to do this as it is automatically handled for you.

Comment: Sadly, I have the exact same run-time error. It does automatically convert it to the Selector-type probably, I tried changing it to `selector: Selector("timerFunc"),` to no avail. My current code is added to the question.

Comment: I just thought, does it matter where I have my NSTimer? Right now it's in viewDidLoad..