# Can't get a subclass of UIView to stop displaying [swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, swift2

I wanted to have a celebration for a certain event in my code. So I took a swift confetti overlay from GitHub (https://github.com/sudeepag/SAConfettiView) and am trying to use it in my project. Basically, if a certain event happens, it starts an NSTimer. I also defined a `showAlert` and `dismissAlert` for popping up a buttonless message on a UIAlertView to say `Congrats!`. When the timer ticks `confettitime` (which starts at 0) for the first time, it begins the confetti overlay (successfully). Then, at the third tick, it activates `showAlert`. The message pops up. It dismisses successfully with `dismissAlert` at the seventh tick of the timer. But I can not get the overlay to hide/the confetti to disappear. As per the instructions in that GitHub project, I call `confettiView.stopConfetti()` to make it stop! But it just keeps on displaying that confetti, freezing my UI. I have tried removing the notifications (no effect), significantly altering the confetti code (no effect), and I just can't find a way to hide the overlay confetti view.

I followed the `Manual Installation` directions in the GitHub project, adding the image assets and `SAConfettiView.swift` to my Swift XCode project. I had to change a couple of the code bits to start because they crashed (like this comment says: https://github.com/sudeepag/SAConfettiView/pull/6), so maybe that is affecting it?

Here's the code of the SAConfettiView, which is the product of that GitHub project:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

public class SAConfettiView: UIView {

public enum ConfettiType {
    case Confetti
    case Triangle
    case Star
    case Diamond
    case Image(UIImage)
}

var emitter: CAEmitterLayer!
public var colors: [UIColor]!
public var intensity: Float!
public var type: ConfettiType!
private var active :Bool!

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    colors = [UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.40, blue:0.27, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.78, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.48, green:0.78, blue:0.64, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.30, green:0.76, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0),
        UIColor(red:0.58, green:0.39, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)]
    intensity = 0.5
    type = .Confetti
    active = false
}

public func startConfetti() {
    emitter = CAEmitterLayer()

    emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: 0)
    emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
    emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 1)

    var cells = [CAEmitterCell]()
    for color in colors {
        cells.append(confettiWithColor(color))
    }

    emitter.emitterCells = cells
    layer.addSublayer(emitter)
    active = true
}

public func stopConfetti() {
    emitter?.birthRate = 0
    active = false
}

func imageForType(type: ConfettiType) -> UIImage? {
    print(type)

    var fileName: String!

    switch type {
    case .Confetti:
        fileName = "Confetti"
    case .Triangle:
        fileName = "triangle"
    case .Star:
        fileName = "star"
    case .Diamond:
        fileName = "diamond"
    case let .Image(customImage):
        return customImage
    }

    print(type)


    return UIImage(imageLiteral: "\(type)")
}

func confettiWithColor(color: UIColor) -> CAEmitterCell {
    let confetti = CAEmitterCell()
    confetti.birthRate = 6.0 * intensity
    confetti.lifetime = 14.0 * intensity
    confetti.lifetimeRange = 0
    confetti.color = color.CGColor
    confetti.velocity = CGFloat(350.0 * intensity)
    confetti.velocityRange = CGFloat(80.0 * intensity)
    confetti.emissionLongitude = CGFloat(M_PI)
    confetti.emissionRange = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
    confetti.spin = CGFloat(3.5 * intensity)
    confetti.spinRange = CGFloat(4.0 * intensity)
    confetti.scaleRange = CGFloat(intensity)
    confetti.scaleSpeed = CGFloat(-0.1 * intensity)
    confetti.contents = imageForType(type)!.CGImage
    return confetti
}

public func isActive() -> Bool {
    return self.active
}
}
```

And here is the relevant code in my project where I call the confetti:

```
var confettitimer = NSTimer()
var confettitime = 0
var alreadyconfettied = false

func confetti() {
confettitime++ 
let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(confettiView)
if confettitime == 1 {
   confettiView.type = .Confetti
   confettiView.startConfetti()
   alreadyconfettied = true
 }
if confettitime == 3 {
   showAlert2()
 }
if confettitime == 7 {
   dismissAlert2()
}
if confettitime == 10 {
   confettiView.stopConfetti()
   lp.confettitimer.invalidate()
   lp.confettitime = 0
}
}

if event == true && alreadyconfettied == false {
    confettitimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "confetti", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    alreadyconfettied = true
 }
```

So sorry for all the code! It would be so helpful if you could tell me **how I can get this confetti overlay to stop!**

---

UPDATE 1 (still not solved):

So I needed to get the ConfettiView creation to happen inside the same function as the `.startConfetti()` and `.stopConfetti()`! There is no way to do this with a timer, because the timer can not call a function when both are inside the same function (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25839597/5700898). Right now, when a certain event happens, it calls the confetti() function...

```
    func confetti() { // called once and only once when the event is triggered.
        let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(confettiView)
    var confettitimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "confettisub", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

   func confettisubfunction() {
            lp.confettitime++
            print(lp.confettitime)
    if confettitime == 1 {
       confettiView.type = .Confetti
       confettiView.startConfetti()
       alreadyconfettied = true
     }
    if confettitime == 3 {
       showAlert2()
     }
    if confettitime == 7 {
       dismissAlert2()
    }
    if confettitime == 10 {
       confettiView.stopConfetti()
       confettitimer.invalidate()
       confettitime = 0
    }
    }
    }
```

But this throws that catastrophic error as I told of above. Basically, this setup is impossible, because the declaration of the view can not be in the same function as where I call it with `.startConfetti()`, and it can not be a global variable/declaration:
- If I do `let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(confettiView)` just before `class ViewController: UIViewController {`, then it does not know what self is, and gives the error "expressions are not allowed at top level."
- If I do that same code to define my Confetti UIView *just inside* the declaration of the view controller, it says "Expected Declaration."

**So how can I fix this and get confetti to rain when a certain event occurs, and how can I stop said confetti with the help of a timer (or really anything that will work??)**

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

UPDATE 2 (Almost solved):

On my global level, I basically do this, and I call `initconfetti()` once per celebration. This lets me have just one confetti view I call `startConfetti()` and `stopConfetti()` on, letting me actually stop the confetti once again!!

```
var confettiView = SAConfettiView()

func initconfetti() {
    confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(confettiView)
}
```

Now I have one problem: I just can't get back to tapping on the original view (my view controller)! How do I kill the confetti view? Maybe I make the bounds 0,0? I have to work on this (I'd still like some suggestions).

I am calling this series of commands when the confetti's over (I don't really know what they all mean):

```
 confettiView.removeFromSuperview()
    confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)))
    view.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
```

but my View Controller is still not responder to taps anywhere, nothing is happening! What's to do? Is there a function I can use to make my old view come to the foreground again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you enter your `confetti` function you create a new `SAConfettiView` and add it to your controller's view.  I didn't follow all the `if` statements but I think it's safe to say that the view you're calling `stopConfetti` on is a different view from the one you used for `startConfetti`.

I suggest creating the view outside of the timer routine and only controlling it via the timer.

Comment: there's nowhere that I can put it that doesn't cause errors (sorry, thanks anyway). Any other suggestions?

Comment: There's probably an answer to that but, since you don't show what you've tried or what the errors are, it's hard to fix them for you.

Comment: I now am showing what I tried and what my errors are (see bottom of my question). I think your answer is correct, I just get errors trying to implement your answer. Thanks for your help so far, and please check out my updated question!

Comment: I finally made the confetti go away (will post more soon) but how do I get touching the original View Controller back? Is there a way to kill that view?

Comment: please see update 2 of my question, how do I let the user use the original (non-confetti) view after the confetti rains down, my app no longer responds to touches (how can I make the original view the first responder again?)!

Comment: After `stopConfetti()`, `confettiView.removeFromSuperview()` should be all you need.  Creating another view and playing with the responders doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: nothing happens, even when I do that! I still can't do anything with the view!

Comment: With the various updates I'm not sure what your code looks like now but, even in the "update 2" section alone, you're creating three instances of `SAConfettiView`.  That can't be right.

Comment: Okay, so in the end, I called my main function twice (oops), which triggered the "event" twice that called confetti. You helped me so much, thank you!! I accepted your answer because you were pretty much right :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comments below the other answer for just about everything, and see below for how to create a subview only once:

First, be sure to only call this once! Do this on the global scope, right underneath the whole `class ViewController : UIViewController {` thing.

```
var confettiView = SAConfettiView()

func initconfetti() {
confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
self.view.addSubview(confettiView)
}
func deinitconfetti() {
confettiView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

That's all. Now call those with the help of an NSTimer.